# Unicode in python 3

Tags: python, file, unicode

I want to convert string, which contains Unicode numbers to usual text. For example, file "input.txt" contains string '\u0057\u0068\u0061\u0074,' and I want to know what does it mean. If string is input in the code like:

```
s = '\u0057\u0068\u0061\u0074'
b = s.encode('utf-8')
print(b)
```

it works perfectly, but if I want to do the same with file I get this result `b'\\u0057\\u0068\\u0061\\u0074'`.

How to fix this problem? Windows 8, encoding of files are 'windows-1251'.

Comment: You cannot **possibly** get that output from the code you gave.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains those unicode escape sequences, then you can use the `unicode_escape` “codec” to interpret them after you read the file contents as a string.

```
>>> s = r'\u0057\u0068\u0061\u0074'
>>> print(s)
\u0057\u0068\u0061\u0074
>>> s.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
'What'
```

Or, you can just read a bytes string directly and decode that:

```
with open('file.txt', 'br') as f:
    print(f.read().decode('unicode_escape'))
```